# Could not create Java Virtual Machine, A fatal Exception has occurred in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server, jvm

Although this questions has been asked before but I am still unable to resolve this error. I am very new to Eclipse and tomcat. There are various solutions as I can see on the internet but which one will specifically fit for my program is what I want to know. I am using tomcat version 7.0.109 and JDK version 15. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks[image: This is the screenshot of my project - DynamicWebProject]

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you did before you got the error? And perhaps check the error log if there are any more details (I don't use Eclipse but this can help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F)

Comment: Check the server configuration (in Eclipse) if the _"Runtime environment"_ property uses an existing JRE. You also have the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` OS environment variable set: remove it, because it overwrites the `-Xmx` parameter you gave. Remove also the `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` command line switch.

Comment: Which release of Eclipse is it?